# Google Sheets newbie query

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm a complete newb when it comes to google sheets.

I want if the Location exists then add the date values to Column B, C, D based on the corresponding location and date in columns h through n.

I'm not sure if this is a query, a vlookup, a match or something else.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hxm0TmHqcf3g1reHctBg4_wc2ebk2SYNFE4g5VTdX2g/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your sheet, and entered this formula.  Give it a shot.  You should be able to figure out the rest on your own.

```
=iferror(vlookup(A2,H:I,2),"not found")
```